# How does OpenCL distribute work items?

Tags: performance, concurrency, opencl, gpu, nvidia

I'm testing and comparing GPU speed up with different numbers of work-items (no work-groups). The kernel I'm using is a very simple but long operation. When I test with multiple work-items, I use a barrier function and split the work in smaller chunks to get the same result as with just one work-item. I measure the kernel execution time using cl_event and the results are the following:

- 1 work-item: 35735 ms
- 2 work-items: 11822 ms (3 times faster than with 1 work-item)
- 10 work-items: 2380 ms (5 times faster than with 2 work-items)
- 100 work-items: 239 ms (10 times faster than with 10 work-items)
- 200 work-items: 122 ms (2 times faster than with 100 work-items)

CPU takes about 580 ms on average to do the same operation.

The only result I don't understand and can't explain is the one with 2 work items. I would expect the speed up to be about 2 times faster compared to the result with just one work item, so why is it 3?

I'm trying to make sense of these numbers by looking at how these work-items were distributed on processing elements. I'm assuming if I have just one kernel, only one compute unit (or multiprocessor) will be activated and the work items distributed on all processing elements (or CUDA cores) of that compute unit. What I'm also not sure about is whether a processing element can process multiple work-items at the same time, or is it just one work-item per processing element?

CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES are 1024 / 1024 / 64 and CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE 1024. Since I'm using just one dimension, does that mean I can have 1024 work-items running at the same time per processing element or per compute unit? When I tried with 1000 work-items, the result was a smaller number so I figured not all of them got executed, but why would that be?

My GPU info: Nvidia GeForce GT 525M, 96 CUDA cores (2 compute units, 48 CUDA cores per unit)

Answer (score 2):

> The only result I don't understand and can't explain is the one with 2
>   work items. I would expect the speed up to be about 2 times faster
>   compared to the result with just one work item, so why is it 3?

The exact reasons will probably be hard to pin down, but here are a few suggestions:

- GPUs aren't optimised *at all* for small numbers of work items. Benchmarking that end of the scale isn't especially useful.
- 35 seconds is a very long time for a GPU. Your GPU probably has other things to do, so your work-item is probably being interrupted many times, with its context saved and resumed every time.
- It will depend very much on your algorithm. For example, if your kernel uses local memory, or a work-size dependent amount of private memory, it might "spill" to global memory, which will slow things down.
- Depending on your kernel's memory access patterns, you might be running into the effects of read/write coalescing. More work items means fewer memory accesses.

> What I'm also not sure about is whether a processing element can process multiple work-items at the same time, or is it just one work-item per processing element?

Most GPU hardware supports a form of SMT to hide memory access latency. So a compute core will have up to some fixed number of work items in-flight at a time, and if one of them is blocked waiting for a memory access or barrier, the core will continue executing commands on another work item. Note that the maximum number of simultaneous threads can be further limited if your kernel uses a lot of local memory or private registers, because those are a finite resource shared by all cores in a compute unit.

Work-groups will normally run on only one compute unit at a time, because local memory and barriers don't work across units. So you don't want to make your groups too large.

One final note: compute hardware tends to be grouped in powers of 2, so it's usually a good idea to make your work group sizes a multiple of e.g. 16 or 64. 1000 is neither, which usually means some cores will be doing nothing.

> When I tried with 1000 work-items, the result was a smaller number so I figured not all of them got executed, but why would that be?

Please be more precise in this question, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: If one work-group runs on one compute unit, and I didn't specify the number of work-items per work-group (assuming that means I have only one work-group), can I be sure that those work-items executed on only one compute unit? Does that mean that those work-items are somehow distributed onto those 48 cores of that one compute unit? I still don't understand the work item size number 1024.

Comment: If you don't specify group size, you don't really have groups at all. Your work items are dispatched to compute units in "natural" parallelism assuming there's no register (private memory) pressure. The way to ensure work items run only on one unit is to put them in a group. Only then can you coordinate between items using local memory and/or barriers. Depending on register and local memory pressure, you may not be able to use the full 1024 work group size (and other hardware will also have lower limits).